# can we have class level variable to store activity results in SWF flow's workflow worker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

In all the SWF Flow documentation for deciders, it's mentioned that the deciders should be deterministic and no random variables should be used in the workflow worker. But I was wondering if we can have class level variables in workflow workers that stores the activity results, so that we can use the results subsequently in the follwing activities..

In the replay scenario, SWF re-populates all the Promises for the activities that are completed.
Does this mean we can store only Promises that are returned or directly the objects that Promises carry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. The workflows are stateful and can have fields that store any data.

Don't think about replay when writing workflow code. If your code is deterministic then you just treat it as normal code and the framework takes care of recovering the state of infra failures.

BTW. Check out [temporal.io](https://www.temporal.io/) which is a much more polished open source version of SWF. For example, it allows writing workflow code synchronously with activity invocations blocking as long as necessary.

Disclaimer: I'm original tech lead of SWF and the current lead of Temporal.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. We saw the said behavior in testing. the major issue we face with SWF is having to bump up the version for every small workflow change and 100K execution limit per domain. Does temporal takes care of these limitations ?

Comment: Yes, Temporal allows versioning code directly without version bumps and has no hard limit on the number of executions per domain (which is called namespace). We tested at Uber up to 200million parallel executions but could go higher if needed.